# Update the Key of a Map

Tags: java, linkedhashmap

I have a Linked Hash Map as follows :

```
Map <Object, Object> test ;
```

With:

The keys are Strings with 4 chars max , like this :

```
1234 -> value1 
2 -> value2
342 -> value3
40 -> value4
```

And I want to update the values of the keys filling the ones that has less than 4 chars , with zeros '0'. For example :

```
1234 -> value1
2000-> value2
3420 -> value 3
4000 -> value 4
```

I've tried

```
  test.forEach((key, value) -> {
                Object storedValue = value;
                Object normalizedKey = StringUtils.rightPad(key.toString(),4,'0');
                test.remove(key);
                test.put(normalizedKey,storedValue);
        });
```

But its giving me ConcurrentMOdificationException.

How can I achieve my goal ?

Comment: You are not supposed to modify the Map/Collection when you are iterating over it

Comment: My apologies, when I closed this I linked a question that addresses modifying an entry's value, but I realize now that modifying an entry's key requires a different approach.

Comment: Here's another question I would vote to close this as a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4235774/1247781

Comment: Creating a new Map is the cleanest way if that is permitted. Another option is to keep a tracker and modify the map based on the tracker.